# Eclipse/Equinox: starting all installed plugins?

Tags: java, osgi, equinox, declarative-services

I have an Eclipse product build using features. All of the services are registered via Declarative Services. As I understand it, the bundle must be started for the Service Component Runtime to pick up and then register the services exposed in each bundle.

I want to automatically start every bundle that's installed in my OSGi runtime. Is there a simple way to do this? The only thing I can find is the Product > Configuration > Start Levels > Auto-Start option. I don't want to have to do this in every product build that I have since I wanted to move to features to group & to start similar bundles together.

Is there a simple/recommended way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the stack overflow question/answer[1], comprehensively discuss your requirement.
or else if you are using a p2-enabled product, you can set the start-by-default param to 'true' within your bundles.info file. But that is a hacky way.

[1] [In Equinox Is it possible to to mark an OSGi bundle as started from its containing feature's p2.inf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077282/in-equinox-is-it-possible-to-to-mark-an-osgi-bundle-as-started-from-its-containi)

Comment: I ended up creating META-INF/p2.inf with the contents `instructions.configure = markStarted(started: true)` in each bundle. I don't want to have to configure per feature. Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy` from your `MANIFEST.MF` and make sure that the attribute `enabled="false"` is **not** in your component definition!

Comment: This only guarantees that once the containing plugin is started all services will be activated. I want to force start all plugins when Equinox start.