# Defining auto start for a plug-in within an eclipse update site project

Tags: eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin, update-site

I have created an update site for my product which consists of a set of Eclipse plug-ins. I want some of the plug-ins start automatically when Eclipse starts after the product is installed.

Actually I know that Eclipse holds auto-start properties of the installed plug-ins in configuration\org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator\bundles.info file and modifying this file manually after plug-in installation works fine. But I want an automated method to provide a user friendly installation process.

Is there a way to specify the plugins to start automatically in a feature based Eclipse update site project? (e.g. something similar to Eclipse Product Configurations).

As I googled, there are some maven based installation tools but I am looking for an easier way via standard Eclipse plug-in development capabilities.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create *plugin/META-INF/p2.inf* file:

```
instructions.configure = \
    setStartLevel(startLevel:4); \
    markStarted(started: true);
```

Look also at:

http://git.eclipse.org/c/equinox/rt.equinox.bundles.git/tree/bundles/org.eclipse.equinox.weaving.caching/META-INF/p2.inf

http://chamibuddhika.wordpress.com/2011/05/18/installing-configuration-files-with-p2-inf-feature-installation/

Comment: related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3077282/in-equinox-is-it-possible-to-to-mark-an-osgi-bundle-as-started-from-its-containi

Answer (score 1):

When you open your product file with the standard *Product Configuration Editor*, you can configure the auto-start setting on the *Configuration* tab in the *Start Levels* section.

When exporting/including this product into an update site, the setting should be taken into account when users install the product.

It is not supported to set auto-start independent of a product.